# ReactJS markdown editor component fails to render

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, codesandbox

I'm learning React at the moment, and I am currently trying out the [Slate Markdown Editor](https://github.com/Canner/canner-slate-editor/tree/master/packages/editors/slate-md-editor) in CodeSandbox. I am trying to initialize a Slate Editor instance like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

import Editor from "slate-md-editor";
const MdEditor = Editor();

<MdEditor />;
```

However, CodeSandbox displays the following error when I attempt to compile my code:

```
at evaluate (https://oxxbg.csb.app/node_modules/canner/slate-icon-codeblock/lib/index.js:80:45z
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.cddc3c052.js:1:98419
X.evaluate
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.cddc3c052.js:1:110543
ye.evaluateTranspiledModule
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.cddc3c052.js:1:120123
c
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.cddc3c052.js:1:110289
evaluate
https://oxxbg.csb.app/node_modules/slate-md-editor/lib/index.js:34:27
z
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.cddc3c052.js:1:98419
X.evaluate
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.cddc3c052.js:1:110543
ye.evaluateTranspiledModule
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.cddc3c052.js:1:120123
c
https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.cddc3c052.js:1:110289
evaluate
/src/index.js:5
  2 | import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  3 | import "./styles.css";
  4 | 
> 5 | import Editor from "slate-md-editor";
  6 | const MdEditor = Editor();
  7 | 
  8 | <MdEditor />;
```

I have not experienced this previously, and I am at a loss of knowing what to do.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone more experienced has some idea of this issue. Thank you in advance.

[Link to the Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sound-oxxbg)

This is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "slate-editor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React testing project",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "4.10.2",
    "immutable": "4.0.0-rc.12",
    "react": "17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "slate": "0.59.0",
    "slate-md-editor": "1.5.4",
    "slate-react": "0.59.0",
    "slate-schema-violations": "0.1.39"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found out later:

### Step 1

Setup a basic React project like so:

```
npx create-react-app slate-editor-demo
cd slate-editor-demo
```

### Step 2

Delete the `App.js`, `App.testing.js`, and `App.css` in the `src/` folder. You should now only have five files in that folder:

- `index.css`
- `index.js`
- `logo.svg`
- `reportWebVitals.js`
- `setupTests.js`

### Step 3

Install dependencies for `slate-md-editor`. Here they are:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
"antd": "^3.8.4",
"immutable": "^3.8.2",
"react": "^16.4.2",
"react-dom": "^16.4.2",
"react-scripts": "1.1.5",
"slate": "^0.40.2",
"slate-react": "^0.12.0",
"slate-schema-violations": "^0.1.39",
"slate-md-editor": "1.5.4",
"web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
```

You can simply copy these dependencies into your `package.json`, and then run `npm install` to update the deps.

### Step 4

Edit your `src/index.js` to look something like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Editor from "./slateMDEditor";
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const options = {
// default settings
  prismOption: {
    // https://github.com/GitbookIO/slate-prism
    onlyIn: node => node.type === 'code_block',
    getSyntax: node => node.data.get('syntax')
  },
  codeOption: {
    // https://github.com/GitbookIO/slate-edit-code
    onlyIn: node => node.type === 'code_block'
  },
  blockquoteOption: {
    // https://github.com/GitbookIO/slate-edit-blockquote
  },
  listOption: {
    // https://github.com/GitbookIO/slate-edit-list
    types: ['ordered_list', 'unordered_list'],
    typeItem: 'list_item',
    typeDefault: 'paragraph'
  }
}

const MdEditor = Editor(options); 

ReactDOM.render(
  <MdEditor onChange={this.onChange} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// Start measuring performance in app
reportWebVitals();
```

### Step 5

Last step: run `npm run start` (if you use NPM), or `yarn start` (if you use yarn). You should see slate markdown editor running smoothly in your browser on localhost.